# How should we handle links to adult content in posts?

Tags: discussion, etiquette, offensive, rules

So [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27677099/2317532) has links to an adult site inside the code, since the website the OP is making is adult in nature. Which is fine.

Is this inappropriate for the site? If so, should we be more explicit in the [flagging guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/flagging)? [Advise askers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to obscure these links before posting?

And if we see such content, should we simply edit it out? Or flag?

Comment: Might be spam... but I would edit it out...

Comment: @rene I agree, but somehow I think this should be in the [StackExchange Model](http://stackoverflow.com/help/flagging)? Alongside, or part of 'rude or offensive'.

Comment: I edited the question and all answers. already cv-ed on it from triage.

Comment: It fits my definition of *otherwise inappropriate for the site* for flagging.

Comment: We can't "make" anyone do anything.  Is your question "should these be edited out"?  Or "should we flag these"?  Or are you proposing a feature to automatically obscure them?

Comment: @psubsee2003 Yes, you worded my question much better. Will edit now.

Comment: Replacing that link with example.com is enough in this case, I think. The rest is about HTML DOM (not dom).

Comment: Why enforce your morality on other people using a question/answer site about programming? There's nothing offensive about nudity or sex. Just answer the question if you can, or if you can't, move on. You can tell, based on the context, what the referenced images contain. If you don't want to see it, don't look! I think this entire discussion is ridiculous.

Comment: @ChrisBaker if nudity or sex is offensive is not the question, but if it is appropriate or belongs to the site. If it is clear the actual URLs of those links are not relevant to the question, and given they may be seen by some people as immoral, why keep them?

Comment: @ChrisBaker This has nothing to do with morality or imposing it on others, more on community values and whether this content is appropriate for this site. I, personally, am not offended by it.

Comment: User has reposted a simular question with links back in it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27679565/php-simple-html-dom-make-variabile

Comment: The link isn't even clickable, so the author's intents aren't to offend or otherwise drive traffic to the site.

Comment: 1) follow link 2) examine for approximately 10 minutes to determine if adult in nature 3) lose interest, take a nap 4) go to step 1 roughly a half hour later

Comment: @ChrisBaker, the question isn't whether sex is offensive.  The question is, is it OK that I peruse StackOverflow while at work, and if so, is it OK if in the course of answering this question I accidentally visit the link in the source without realizing where it will send me while at work.  Not saying it's particularly intelligent to just follow random links in code, but I might typically visit a site to view the HTML directly when the question is about traversing the DOM to get a better idea of what the user is trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

I give you this answer from Jeff when a similar question came up on Web Apps not long after it launched back in 2010:

[Are questions about “adult” web apps on or off topic?](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/364/are-questions-about-adult-web-apps-on-or-off-topic/367#367)

> No, I don't think we want this, as it would cause us to get globally banned from web filtering software.
>
> **So including adult links, or even mentioning adult sites by name, is explicitly not allowed**.

While the situation is not exactly the same - you should be able to ask your question on Stack Overflow without referencing the adult content directly.

Comment: "...you should be able to ask your question on Stack Overflow without referencing the adult content directly." Excellent point and answer!

Comment: I accepted this response (not that accepting means anything) solely because Chris made the very important point of - If it doesn't need to be there, and if it is a concern for a significant number of users, then it'd be better to not include it.

Answer (score 40):

This type of situation occurs for 2 reasons.

- The OP didn't think about obscuring it on an otherwise valid attempt to ask a question
- The OP is a spammer in disguise and is hiding spam links within the "code" of their question.

Usually it is going to be pretty obvious what the user is doing.  Someone who has somewhat of a history on the site (multiple question, answers, or edits) and has not performed this type of action before is not likely going to be a spammer.  There is of course a small chance that this could happen, but it is unlikely someone who go through the effort to creating an account and building of some sort of history just to post 1 spam link is really not likely.  They would have a history of doing so.

Whereas a brand new account, asking a hastily written question is more likely to be a spammer, although still could be an innocent mistake.

The reason I spelled this out is Spam/Offensive flags carry a very heavy penalty for the user.  You must use them **only** when appropriate.  It would be unfair to punish someone for posting spam or an offensive link when it was a simple mistake.  If it is clearly an attempt at spamming the site, then flag away, but if not, then editing is probably the correct course of action.  Once the link is edited out, you can flag the post using a custom flag and explain the situation in brief detail.

This is for 2 reasons

- First, the moderator will be able to see more of the user's history than you can.  Maybe they do have a habit of doing this and the moderator can take appropriate action.
- Second, if the links are especially bad, the moderator can ask a developer to remove the original revision so it is not present in the revision history of the question.

Comment: Not so much obvious. What if the user already posted a question with intentional spam, it's been deleted by the review and we cannot see it ?

Comment: Also it's going to be pretty obvious from context. Redtube is globally ranked 108 by Alexa. The idea that they are employing someone to drive traffic by hiding links inside code snippets on StackOverflow would be ridiculous IMO.

Comment: @TLama which is why I said "you can flag the post using a custom flag and explain the situation in brief detail".  A mod will be able to tell if this is a one time accident or a pattern.  And they can take action at that time.  If you insist on using spam flags anytime someone accidentally posts a NSFW link, you are only going to end up with most of them declined because mods do look at the users history and will decline unfair spam flags.

Comment: I think a "sensible/nsfw" flagging could help, no direct indication of "spam" but some sort of mild warning, that viewers can add to the question to catch honest mistakes on the OP side

Answer (score 10):

Answering not on that particular case but on the general case:

> How should we handle links to adult content in posts?

**I don't want *any* adult content directly linked from SO.** Whatever could be the reason. So I'm strongly in favor of immediately editing the offensive posts to remove direct link -- and if the link is "required" by the question, to close it as "off-topic". Even if the question is deleted, *edit* is required as long as the page is still visible for 10k+.

Please remember that depending the place of the world you live, "adult content" might clearly be illegal. In addition, lots of us are consulting SO either at work or at home -- and I don't want expose my colleagues or my child to inappropriate content.

Comment: At my last job, the filtering software would ban pages that *linked* to what it deemed "objectionable content". Enough of those pages and the whole domain would get added to a blacklist. Which would mean, no more SO at work.

Answer (score 2):

Considering the amount of views that low quality question got, perhaps we should include more links to adult content in our posts. Kidding of course, but interesting to consider.

Personally, I find the content in that question rather amusing as it is only text. It is also in html element attributes so it may be a little hard for someone to parse at a glance.

Nothing in the post is insulting a particular group directly. That said, I understand that some may feel insulted by seeing that material, it is not directed at them.

I don't think that obfuscating the material is damaging to the post (as has been done), but I also think that these issues are so few and far between that they should be handled on a case to case basis in the same way all other content is handled by the community.