# Flag a post (question or answer) as "offensive, abusive, or hate speech", or use a custom flag?

Tags: support, flags, offensive

I recently ran into a question that contained two sentences that were problematic. The first one was just rude. The second was hate speech (advocating genocide). Neither could have been interpreted as innocuous. Apart from these two sentences, the rest of the post was fine.

I handled it by editing out the problematic language and using a custom flag to bring it to the attention of moderators because hateful language should not be tolerated. It would not have been correct to just edit out the language and leave it at that.

It occurred to me that there is a flag specifically for "offensive, abusive, or hate speech". I take it (perhaps incorrectly) that such a flag would be prioritized over the mass of custom flags. So I spent a split second considering this option. However, I figured it would be better to edit the question right away before the whole thing turned into a shouting match. (The question was on Meta and had been bumped to the top of the list by the edit that added the problematic language.) And I figured that once the question was edited, the evidence of hate speech would be buried into an old revision. So I decided that such a flag would be at risk of being declined, and no warning given to the user.

So I edited, and used a custom flag that pointed exactly to the revision that contained the hate speech. Was it better to edit and use a custom flag, rather than editing and using the "offensive, abusive, or hate speech" flag? If yes, then does this mean that we should use the "offensive, abusive, or hate speech" flag **when the post cannot be sanitized**? For instance, a post which is nothing else than a racist rant.

As I recall, the post was deleted by a moderator shortly after I flagged it.

Comment: I hate PHP, West Ham supporters and jQuery.  Does that count?

Comment: @MartinJames the first and third are perfectly justifiable and rational. Soccer players though (do you hate people who say soccer rather than football)... unless they're rioting tend to be ok.

Comment: No link?!?!  You suck and should be placed in a camp for not linking to the question.

Comment: I don't see a flag in your flag history that matches what you're talking about, so it's hard to say if you should have done something differently.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker Looking at my helpful flags on Meta, I can get to it by searching for "edited out". (Not providing links or names out of deference to the "don't air the dirty laundry" principle that I perceive moderators to follow.) Note that I'm not asking about *that specific case* but *generally speaking*. I've considered only two cases in my question: a post that has only a portion that can be edited out (which I what I ran into), and a post that can't be edited into shape. Maybe the set of cases should be divided into finer distinctions.

Answer (score 21):

> I recently ran into a question that contained two sentences that were problematic. The first one was just rude. The second was hate speech (advocating genocide).

Breaking it down:

- "The first one was just rude.": if it was "mildly" rude but the question otherwise had merit, then I'd have done what you did, edit it, and then custom flag the moderators. If it was strongly rude (I know, this is subjective), then see the point made below.
- "The second was hate speech (advocating genocide).": If I saw this, I'd leave the text as is, flag the question as "offensive, abusive, or hate speech" and hope that the whole thing were deleted, and the poster banned for life, regardless of any possible merit elsewhere in the post. There's **no** place for this here on this site or on any site for that matter.
- "that contained two sentences": These **two** sentences were in the same post? If so, then this just reinforces that my second point was valid.

Comment: I support your point 2. In my experience, the "offensive/spam" flags are handled very promptly by moderators, so there's not much risk of the unacceptable text sticking around for too long.

Answer (score 7):

First, for the borderline stuff, see my answer [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/281251/how-should-we-handle-links-to-adult-content-in-posts/281252#281252).

Short version is do not use the offensive or spam flags unless the post deserves it as those flags, when accepted, carry a very heavy penalty for the user.  You can read more about the criteria for offensive flags in the MSE [faq](/questions/tagged/faq) post [What are the “spam” and “rude or abusive” (offensive) flags, and how do they work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58032/what-are-the-spam-and-offensive-flags-and-how-do-they-work).

> What makes something offensive and when should I flag it?
>
> Even if a post is a bad post for some reason or another, it is probably not offensive. The Offensive flag is meant to be used only in extreme cases, like hate speech, or abuse.
>
> For example, if a user posts obscene images to the site, that should be flagged as offensive. But if someone says something bad about your favorite technology, that probably doesn't apply.
>
> As a rule of thumb, if you can't justify something as being hate speech, or abuse, you shouldn't mark the post as offensive. Instead, you should down-vote the post.
>
> When you decide to flag a post Offensive, you will get a warning dialog. Take this time to decide if the post is really offensive.

But beyond that, as I also suggest, the revision history still would contain the racist bull****, so editing out is not sufficient if the post is not quite offensive enough. So, if the post is offensive enough to warrant an offensive flag, then nothing else should be necessary.  These flags go to the moderators, so they will see it.  But if you think the offensive material is borderline, or not quite offensive enough and contains enough of an answer that complete deletion would remove an otherwise valid answer, then definitely edit the post and flag for a moderator.  They can ask a developer to scrub the post to remove the offensive material from the revision history.