# Vagueness of Spam flag / flags in general?

Tags: discussion, flags, spam, rude-or-abusive

When a question contains links to pornographic material, material intended to be of sexual nature, explicit text or all of the above, are users powerless at flagging content as spam because the rules are so vague in the context that there is no clear understanding by both users and mods?

An example as [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73254854/my-code-doesnt-work-correctly-with-regex), particularly refer to the link text and linked content.

Comment: That doesn't appear to be spam. Spam has to have _intent_ to be spam, here it's likely just a misguided user who posted a bad question. Closing is the correct response, not flagging as spam or R/A. If you really wanted you could've edited the post to contain the regex and example with some less explicit URLs.

Comment: A Spam/R/A flag is not appropriate here because there's absolutely no context in the question to indicate that there's anything offensive about it. The link is to a regex tool that's used very often on the site. If you personally find the example text in the linked website to be offensive, you need to raise a custom flag explaining the issue. A custom flag might get declined as well, but at least the handling mod knows what you're referring to.

Comment: @Gerhard It's not so much that they're "ok", it's more there's no clear intent. Are they linking that specifically for the purpose of spamming? Then it's spam. Are they linking to cause offense? Then it's rude or abusive. But if the user just posted a question which happened to contain links to rude stuff because that's what their code is about, and they failed to edit it to be safe for work? That's just misguided, and shouldn't come with the harsh penalties that flags can come with. [psubsee's answer here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/281252/3270037) covers it well.

Comment: @Gerhard It _could_ be another spam tactic, but because of how bad the penalties are from spam flags and the fact that we can't be certain (although mods have tools to help them), I wouldn't flag unless I was sure because there's every chance they're not spammers.

Comment: When in doubt raise a custom mod flag. That allows you to explain what is going on / special / weird / worth noting about the post and what it links to. You can explain that bringing the example over in the question is a no-no. And you can always end with something like: *is this a one-of or does this user post more content with links to dubious content*. I haven't have many of many of these custom flags declined.

Comment: If it's not clear that a post you flag leads to obscene content then you need to use a custom flag & explain that. The generic rude/abusive flag is for when a mod can look at the post & immediately see the bad content. If content is obviously R/A multiple people will flag it & the post will be handled without mod intervention.

Answer (score 16):

**General guidance for problematic content**

We did actually *just recently* have an issue with a user who made several posts which linked *directly* to a nude image (hosted on the i.stack.imgur domain).This type of thing can and does happen from time to time. These were appropriately red-flag and subsequently removed for that reason. In general, if there are issues in *the post itself* (including direct links away) then a red-flag is likely appropriate. So there are definitely situations where R/A flags can be used for non-promotional problematic content.

Probably also worth noting that most mods (in my experience) are not too bothered *which* red-flag is used if the content *is* problematic and need of removal. Additionally most (again in my experience) will investigate at least to some extent what you meant by the red-flag.

There's always the option to cast an "in need of moderator intervention" flag to further explain the situation (as has been mentioned already) if there really needs to be more context as to *why* this (perhaps seemingly innocuous) content needs to be removed. I also find it helpful to cast a mod-flag when I'm unsure, because the incident is now noted on the account and can be reviewed later if it becomes a further issue.

---

**Programmers can and do work with this type of content**

Having said all this, however, programmers can and do work with profanity, abusive content, pornographic content, and otherwise explicit content. Programmers do implement solutions for the "protection" of others and to derive protections "threat" analysis is often necessary. This idea is not dissimilar to [Should questions about programming viruses and malware be allowed?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/262656/15497888)

A counterexample that comes to mind in this particular case would be a pattern-based ad blocker or traffic filter. Trying to *detect* (with regex) ad patterns that should *not* be displayed for their content is both a programming problem and probably not something that would be easily modifiable to someone unfamiliar with regex (changing the test string without affecting the ability for a pattern to be developed can be error prone).

**Would a disclaimer or context be helpful?**

Sure. People should know what they're looking at, especially in contexts where proceeding further could get them in trouble.

**Would a test string that did not contain links to adult content be preferable to many people?**

Probably. A small representative sample is helpful in most questions and one that doesn't expose others to unnecessary content is preferable to most people: even when the content is just unneeded and not potentially abusive.

Comment: Years and years ago now, Head Office sent teams to investigate the downloading of gigabytes of porn. Turned out a new version of Eclipse had just come out that had support for some then-new features of Java 5. Those folks at Playboy did a lot of web development and hosted an Eclipse mirror. They also had really, really fast pipes, so most of our Java devs were directed to Playboy when they updated.

Answer (score 12):

So this is a very specific and specialized case that is worth talking about, specifically because I know that reacting to something like this is, well, obvious.

The *content* of the post contains links to some place undesirable, or undesirable subcontext.  I wouldn't wanna follow those links on my personal laptop, let alone my work laptop.

The *question* being asked is still technically a valid question and very likely a dupe, since the user is looking for a specific string in the JSON structure.  You don't use regex for JSON.  You use something else.  Surely someone else has an answer for this.

A moderator would be looking at something blatant and obvious, in which the poster clearly and definitively intends to link to or display pornographic material on the site, and would likely decline the flag is there was still something that could be done to the post to make that *not* the focus.  In here, there is still a shadow of doubt that the OP is looking to accomplish something with regex from a part of the 'net that we'd prefer didn't blend over here.

(Also too, the links are essentially two clicks away from the main post.  Someone has to be deliberate in following those.)

What I'd do if I were half-bothered would be to remove the URL since it's not a part of the search string anyway, and clean up some of the other language.  Then it'd be suitable to embed the data structure on the site *and* a new Regex101 link that contains the same spirit as the OP.  Gotta give people the benefit of the doubt sometimes.

(If they revert *that* edit then you've done everything you should and you can flag safely with that justification.)

Comment: @Gerhard It's not a "danger" to them. It's a danger to adults at work because they could get fired.

Comment: @Gerhard:  I feel like the first click is an accident, but the second one in which you ***literally have to highlight the entire link and either copy and paste it into your browser or right-click to open the link*** is most certainly *not* an accident.  Regex101 doesn't generate hyperlinks to click.

Comment: @Gerhard Exactly. So if you don't want to access that content, don't follow the links. I'm not claiming that it should be explicitly allowed (since you can just substitute explicit examples for more benign ones), just that it's not R/A material.

Comment: @Gerhard That's not at all what I said and I don't think your reaction is constructive or reasonable. You seem to be treating a link that contains code which contains a link to a site that contains adult material as if it is some serious transgression and a massive violation of children's safety, which is a ridiculous position. If you're going to give up on a site because it decides to close a question or edit out adult content rather than validating your R/A flags, then I don't know what to say.

Answer (score 3):

The correct action would have been to edit the content out and replace it with something a little more acceptable for a broad audience or flag it for more attention so that a moderator could decide what to do with it. If the post was not made with the intention of being rude or abusive and it could be easily salvaged by replacing specific URLs with [reserved example domains](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2606.html), then it should be.

**R/A was not the right flag to raise here.**